# Deserializing json into new objects

Tags: c#, json

I'm reading some Json from an api which I don't own, and therefore, I can't change the response.  When I'm deserializing the Json into C# objects using Newtonsoft, I'm running into a problem with the 'ChangedAttributes' field.  When creating these classes, Visual Studio wants to create a class for 'Sex', and one for 'MaritalStatus', but they aren't being populated.  Furthermore, the list of ChangedAttributes can be any number of hundreds of different possibilities.  So, I'd like to deserialize those attributes into a generic type class, say, something like:

```
public class Attribute
{

public string Name {get;set;}
public string Old {get;set;}
public string New {get;set;}
}
```

Can someone tell me how I might accomplish that using Newtonsoft?  Here's a sample of the Json that I'm trying to parse:

```
{
  "Context" : [ {
    "PersonName" : "Smith, Bob",
    "PersonNumber" : "001246",
    "PrimaryPhoneNumber" : "",
    "PersonId" : "300000009560451",
    "WorkerType" : "EMP",
    "PeriodType" : "E",
    "DMLOperation" : "UPDATE",
    "EffectiveStartDate" : "2004-08-27",
    "EffectiveDate" : "2004-08-27"
  } ],
  "Changed Attributes" : [ {
    "Sex" : {
      "old" : null,
      "new" : "M"
    }
  }, {
    "MaritalStatus" : {
      "old" : null,
      "new" : "S"
    }
  } ]
}
```

Here are the C# classes that VS generated for me:

```
public class AtomFeed_Empupdate
{
    public AtomFeed_Empupdate_Context[] Context { get; set; }
    public AtomFeed_Empupdate_ChangedAttribute[] ChangedAttributes { get; set; }
}

public class AtomFeed_Empupdate_Context
{
    public string PersonName { get; set; }
    public string PersonNumber { get; set; }
    public string WorkEmail { get; set; }
    public string PrimaryPhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string PersonId { get; set; }
    public string WorkerType { get; set; }
    public string PeriodType { get; set; }
    public string DMLOperation { get; set; }
    public string EffectiveStartDate { get; set; }
    public string EffectiveDate { get; set; }
}

public class AtomFeed_Empupdate_ChangedAttribute
{
    public AtomFeed_Empupdate_Sex Sex { get; set; }
    public AtomFeed_Empupdate_Maritalstatus MaritalStatus { get; set; }
}

public class AtomFeed_Empupdate_Sex
{
    public string old { get; set; }
    public string _new { get; set; }
}

public class AtomFeed_Empupdate_Maritalstatus
{
    public string old { get; set; }
    public string _new { get; set; }
}
```

And here is how I am deserializing the Json:

```
AtomFeed_Empupdate eu = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AtomFeed_Empupdate>(json);
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You may change `Attribute` class a little bit and decorate it with `JsonProperty` attribute with proper names

```cs
public class Attribute
{
    [JsonProperty("old")]
    public string Old { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("new")]
    public string New { get; set; }
}
```

And use `Dictionary<string, Attribute>[]` (since you have an array of key-value pairs) for `Changed Attributes` JSON token

```cs
public class AtomFeed_Empupdate
{
    public AtomFeed_Empupdate_Context[] Context { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Changed Attributes")]
    public Dictionary<string, Attribute>[] ChangedAttributes { get; set; }
}
```